# How do you display a pane in an organic group?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, panels

I'm trying to create a menu of subgroups for organic groups in d7.  I've copied the og list view and made a new view called og subgroups.  I made a pane display and configured the pane's argument to be Og group ID from context.  I also added the contextual filter: (group) OG group: Og group ID and the relationship: Group: Node group.

When I enter a group ID in the preview field of the view, it loads the appropriate menu items. When I go to the Group variant for the node template in panels, and add the pane as content in the appropriate region panels shows that the argument is group ID, but if I view the group it does not display the pane.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do on the **view content pane**:

- Relationships: "Group membership: Node group membership"
- Contextual Filters: "(group membership) OG membership: Group gid"
- Pane settings: Argument input: From context > Og group ID

On the **panel** contexts:

- Contexts: OG group > Og group from context

Then you should add the view content pane to the panel pane and the argument should automaticaly be set to "OG membership: Group gid" > "OG group".

These are required for it to work, and I'm currently using them.